# Pass data from a ListView to another Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview fetching data from SqLite Db. I need to get the data that is being clicked in the listview and show it in another activity in a listview.

I have tried using shared preferences but i could only get one data at a time and display it in another activity as a textview.

I have no idea how to all show the selected data in a listview or create a listview from the selected data, need help.

my search activity

```
  listContent1.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
  listContent1.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener); 



             private ListView.OnItemClickListener listContentOnItemClickListener = new ListView.OnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

      Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

      String item_content1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_FOODNAME));
      String item_content2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CALORIES));
      arlene = arlene + Integer.parseInt(item_content2);
      String item = String.valueOf(" Food Name: " + item_content1 ) + "\n" +
              " Calories: " +  item_content2;

       Toast.makeText(Search.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      

       food.setText(item_content1);
       calories.setText(String.valueOf(arlene));


       Intent myIntent = new Intent(Search.this, Foodlog.class);
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString("SQLITEDATA1", food.getText().toString()); 
       bundle.putString("SQLITEDATA2", calories.getText().toString()); 
       myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
       startActivity(myIntent); 
  }
```

here is my foodlog activity

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.foodlog);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

     foodnum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodNum);
     remaining = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.remainingNum);
     totalnum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalNum);  
     foodlog = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
       if( bundle != null){
       String food = bundle.getString("SQLITEDATA1");
       String calories = bundle.getString("SQLITEDATA2");

       String[] values = new String[] { food, calories }; //That you got from your intent bundle
       LVAdapter adapter = new LVAdapter(this, R.layout.foodlist, values);
       setListAdapter(adapter);

       }
```

hope you can help me

```
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        start activity ComponentInfo{me.mojica.caloriewatch/me.mojica.caloriewatch.Foodlog}:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at  android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at me.mojica.caloriewatch.Foodlog.onCreate(Foodlog.java:22)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-04 23:40:18.572: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

i have edited this based on the answers. still i cant get it running. help please.

Comment: Attach a "Bundle" with "Intent" for second activity.

Comment: ive tried that but how can i create a listview from it? please help me.

Comment: I will help you, you first zero down where your problem is?

Comment: i need to get the data on onitemclick and pass it to the other activity and from that clicked item, i need to create a listview from it.

Comment: What data does your first listview contain? Can you draw and image if your first Listview in Paint and attach with the question?

Comment: ok. please wait and help me with this. thanks a lot

Comment: i cant add an image. too bad for me

Comment: You need to understand about "Bundle" and "Intent" - How to start an Activity?

Comment: i know about, im having a hard time how to create a lsitview from it. im so sorry im new to android and java.

Comment: @codingcrow help please

Answer (score 1):

You pass an Extra bundle with data to your next activity using Intent when you click the ListView item.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("SQLITEDATA1", food.getText().toString()); 
myIntent.putExtra("SQLITEDATA2", calories.getText().toString()); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Using this data you should fill the ListView by making a custom ListView adapter.

```
public class SimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public SimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);        
    textView.setText(values[position]);     
    return rowView;
  }
}
```

To fill the ListView in your other Activity:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String food = myIntent.getStringExtra("SQLITEDATA1");
    String calories = myIntent.getStringExtra("SQLITEDATA2");
    String[] values = new String[] { food, calories }; //That you got from your intent bundle
    SimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new SimpleArrayAdapter(this, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

}
```

I recommend [reading this entire tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: what data will i pass in the intent sir? im so sorry. im super new to thiw and Is the listview adapter will be in my first class or will i make another one just for that?

Comment: @michelle.mo Looks like you are saving the clicked data in Shared Preference and then reading it again in the next activity.If so, instead you should use Intent.

Comment: sorry sirs. i have no idea how to pass the data and from what ive been reading, they suggests Shared Preferences

Comment: hey sir, can i get your email address or something maybe, please. i need help, badly with my project.

Comment: Check my edit one more time. Look closely how I pass 2 strings (calories and food) over to the new Activity. You should only use Shared Preferences if you want to SAVE the data when you close the app. But using the custom adapter is still the same if you can get the data back.

Comment: hello sir. ive tried using the codes, im having an error here   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, values); please help me out?

Comment: The constructor ArrayAdapter(Foodlog, String[]) is undefined.

Comment: O sry, ArrayAdapter is a default class of android so I renamed everything to "SimpleArrayAdapter".

Comment: whenever i will click an item on a list, my application will forced close.

Comment: I'm not psychic, post the stack trace of the error. Is it a nullpointer exception?

Comment: @michelle.mo Add your layout file for Listview to the question.

Comment: @michelle.mo See all the answer for you problem https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Your+content+must+have+a+ListView+whose+id+attribute+is+'android.R.id.list'&aq=f&oq=Your+content+must+have+a+ListView+whose+id+attribute+is+'android.R.id.list'&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.15538&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8